# Crystal Report: Display 0.00 for duplicate values

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am making a crystal report which displays values from database. Now the values from db contains duplicate values.

I need that duplicate values should be suppressed and should display 0.00

For Ex.

Value

- 250.00
- 250.00
- 250.00

Should display

- 250.00
- 0.00
- 0.00

I have applied "Suppress Duplicate" to the column but don't know how to display 0.00 there.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not check **Suppress if Duplicated.**. You need to write formula for **Display String**.

For example,

```
if PreviousIsNull ({object.field}) then 
  cstr({object.field})
else
if CurrentFieldValue=previous({object.field}) then 
   '0.00' 
else 
  cstr({object.field})
```

EDIT:

```
  if PreviousIsNull ({object.field}) then 
      cstr({object.field})
    else
    if {object.field}=previous({object.field}) then 
       '0.00' 
    else 
      cstr({object.field})
```

Comment: thanks for comment. But it gives me error at CurrentFieldValue telling "This function can only be used in field formatting formulas"..

Comment: What if i need to do summation of that column where formula has been written under "display string"? I did Summation but that doesn't ignore duplicate. hence the total of my value comes to 750.0 instead of 250.0

Comment: You can use {object.field} instead of CurrentFieldValue.

Comment: Please refer to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018368/crystal-report-is-previousnull-prints-incorrect-data

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Field and click on Format Object Then click on Customize button
Then there is a "Show zero value as" with dropdown to Default.
Select that dropdown value to 0 instead of default.