# Summation of a field in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

please refer to the link:

[Crystal Report: Display 0.00 for duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966511/crystal-report-display-0-00-for-duplicate-values)

In that question, i need to display sum as 250.00, but it come as 750.00

Let me know if any query.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake - as Arvo has stated you need to use a Running Total for this as the Sum functionality cannot evaluate a formula of this type.

Your Running Total should be setup similar to this:

**Field to Summarize** : {FieldName}

**Type of Summary** : sum

Evalute:

**On Change of Field** : {FieldName}

Reset:

**Use a Formula**

```
if PreviousIsNull ({FieldName}) then 
  {FieldName}
else
if {FieldName}=previous({FieldName}) then 
   0
else 
  {FieldName}
```

Comment: thanks for input, but the formula that i have provided doesn't work under custom made formulas. It throw error as at CurrentFieldValue telling "This function can only be used in field formatting formulas"

Comment: thanks for update. The summation of this formula says that the field cannot be summarized..

Comment: that clicked! (with some little modifications though.. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

You need to use running total field - from problem description you have some one-to-many relationships, which multiply resulting rows (and 'normal' totals).