# Crystal Report: Is PreviousNull prints incorrect data

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

Some days back i posted a question in SO at [Crystal Report: Display 0.00 for duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966511/crystal-report-display-0-00-for-duplicate-values)

The question was to remove duplicate values and the report should display 0.00 instead. It was very kind of @adatapost that he posted a solution.

**Now,it is throwing very irritating and awkward problem.**

The 7th record is showing up 0.00

Hence, if the record was like before as

400.00

 400.00

 400.00

 500.00

 500.00

 500.00

 600.00

 600.00

 600.00

After that formula applied is showing something like

400.00

 0.00

 0.00

500.00

0.00

0.00

0.00  (THIS IS INCORRECT-- IT SHOULD BE 600.00)

0.00

0.00

Can you please throw some light in this issue? I appreciate your inputs & efforts.

thanks!

Comment: expecting a solution... help me please..

Comment: 3 hours since the question post but no reply...awaiting comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a formula named 'Amount'.

Add the following to the formula:

```
If PreviousIsNull ({table.field}) Or Previous ({table.field}) <> {table.field} Then
    {table.field}
Else
    0
```

Use this formula instead of the database field.

Comment: @craig: thanks for valuable input, but that doesn't help..it still showing up the same result...don't know why such thing is happening as no such condition has been put anywhere..

Comment: @romil: are you certain that the data contains the 600s?

Comment: @adatapost: the formula field isn't necessarily a better option, i actually like and use display-string formulae, but i thought a formula field might be easier to test.

Comment: @craig: Yes i am sure that data contains 600.

Comment: @romil: so, the formula field ({@Amount}), produces the same results as the database field {table.amount} with the display-string formula?